# mappingJarLocations not working for jars present in classpath

Tags: spring

We have a Java Maven Project. Integrated with Springs and Hibernate. Hibenate files are present in dependent jar build from maven.

I am getting this exception. Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [.authentication.1.1.jar] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist.

In spring mappingJarLocations configuration as follows

```
<property name="mappingJarLocations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath*:authentication*.jar</value>
      </list>
 </property>
```

I have gone throw several blogs where configuration specified as follows
    
          
            /WEB-INF/lib/authentication*.jar

As Mine is not a web project i dont have option to put WEB-INF structure.
Ours is simple java maven project.

Just we need to read hbm files from jar which is present in classpath.

and one more thing i want to share is when i run my project in eclipse it is working.
but when i make as runnable jar its and run from command promt its not picking hbm files from jar files.

"Please help me to fix this issue".

Thanks Regards,
Uday

Comment: As you told it is a maven project what you can do is make a directory lib put all the required jar while creating the jar add the lib folder dependency in it